# What is the command in MacOS terminal to sort grep output by file creation date in descending order?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal, grep

I want to recursively find all files that contain the string "aloha" in a directory dir. I will use grep command to do this, and the output will be a list of file paths. I want to sort them by their creation date (descending order). I understand that on MacOS the kernel actually stores the file creation date unlike for other systems, so I know this is possible but I just cant figure it out.

```
grep -iRl  "aloha" dir/ | sort -k1 -n
grep -iRl  "aloha" dir/ | ls -U
grep -iRl  "aloha" dir/ |  xargs stat -f '%c %N'|sort
```

Given following files are in directory dir:

```
file1.txt - created on 1/2/2019
file2.txt - created on 1/3/2019
```

the output of the command should be:

```
file2.txt
file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls -Ut` can do this. But `ls` doesn't get the filenames from standard input, so you can't pipe the output directly to it. It requires the filenames to be command line arguments, so you can use `xargs` to convert standard input to arguments.

```
grep -iRl "aloha" dir | xargs ls -Ut
```

However, this won't work well if any of the filenames contain whitespace in their names. Use the `--null` option to `grep` to make it output a null byte after each filename, and the -0`option to`xargs` to make it use this as the delimiter between filenames.

```
grep -iRl --null "aloha" dir | xargs -0 ls -Ut
```

Comment: This won't produce the file list in sorted order because xargs calls ls sequentially based on the order that grep outputted the file.

Comment: @WaltDe But `ls -Ut` reorders them.

Comment: To be fair, if there are so many files that `xargs` needs to split it into multiple invocations, they'll only be sorted within each group. Practically, I don't think that ever happens.

Comment: Good point and I had to look up what the current arg limit is on Mac.  It's 262144 which will handle a lot of filenames.

Comment: And what I was thinking is the POSIX arg limit that is only 4096 which can easily be hit using xargs with filenames.   But it's been a long time since I've worked in a POSIX system so I probably need to unlearn this limit.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will do the trick.

```
find dir -name '*aloha*' -exec stat -f "%B %N" {} \; | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

I'm using find instead of grep because it performed significantly faster then grep when I was testing on my system. Also, I'm using the -exec option of find instead of xargs because it easily handle files with spaces.

Let's break this down.

```
find dir
```

This will recursivly find all files in the directory dir

```
-name '*aloha*'
```

Only select files that contain the aloha

```
-exec stat -f "%B %N" {} \;
```

Execute the stat command on every selected file and output the creation time in epoch and the name of the file.  The '{} \;' are special syntax to find where {} substitutes the name of the file and '\;' terminates the options to -exec.

```
| sort -n
```

Next do a numeric sort on the creation epoch time.

```
| cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Finally only display the file name by splitting the line on spaces and display all fields from the 2nd position onwards.

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou.

I changed: 

* `%B` to `%m` to sort by `m`odified time rather than `B`irth time
* `sort -n` to `sort -nr` to show the most recent at the top
* appended `| head -n10` to get only the most recent 10 files